# Not Able to Append Values of Selected Columns into an Existing Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am able to select values of 3 columns of DataFrame A `db_a` but not able to append them into an existing `db_b` (I need to use append becauese eventually I will put this in a loop)

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?

```
selected_columns_a = df_a.iloc[:, 0:3]
selected_columns_a_values = selected_columns_a.values
selected_columns_a_values = pd.DataFrame(selected_columns_a_values, columns=None)


df_b = df_b.append(selected_columns_a_values, ignore_index=True)

print(df_b)
```

In return I am getting a 3 column wide 10 column tall table of just `NaN`

I also used the `pd.concat([df_b, selected_columns_a_values], ignore_index=True)` but this is adding three columns into the data frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) has been deprecated since `pandas` version 1.4.0. You can get the same results using [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

```py
# setup
df_a = pd.DataFrame({"a": range(10), "b": range(10), "c": range(10)})
# an arbitrary df
df_b = pd.DataFrame({"d": range(5)})
```

## To add rows (append):

```py
cols_to_add = ["a", "c"]
out = pd.concat(
    [df_b, df_a[cols_to_add]],
)
print(out)
```

```py
     d    a    c
0  0.0  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  NaN  NaN
2  2.0  NaN  NaN
3  3.0  NaN  NaN
4  4.0  NaN  NaN
0  NaN  0.0  0.0
1  NaN  1.0  1.0
2  NaN  2.0  2.0
3  NaN  3.0  3.0
4  NaN  4.0  4.0
5  NaN  5.0  5.0
6  NaN  6.0  6.0
7  NaN  7.0  7.0
8  NaN  8.0  8.0
9  NaN  9.0  9.0
```

You can optionally ignore the index.

```py
# same as `out.reset_index(drop=True)`
out = pd.concat(
    [df_b, df_a[cols_to_add]],
    ignore_index=True,
)
print(out)
```

```py
      d    a    c
0   0.0  NaN  NaN
1   1.0  NaN  NaN
2   2.0  NaN  NaN
3   3.0  NaN  NaN
4   4.0  NaN  NaN
5   NaN  0.0  0.0
6   NaN  1.0  1.0
7   NaN  2.0  2.0
8   NaN  3.0  3.0
9   NaN  4.0  4.0
10  NaN  5.0  5.0
11  NaN  6.0  6.0
12  NaN  7.0  7.0
13  NaN  8.0  8.0
14  NaN  9.0  9.0
```

## NOTE

Concatenating without matching columns will produce `NaN`s in cells that don't align. If you want to `concat` and ignore the columns, the shapes of the dataframes need to match, similar to a [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) in SQL.

```py
out = pd.concat(
    [
        df_b["d"],
        # Unpacking the values of each column into a series.
        # Each will be concatenated in the order of `cols_to_add`.
        *(df_a[col] for col in cols_to_add)
    ],
    ignore_index=True,
)
# `out` has type `pd.Series`
print(out)
```

```py
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     0
6     1
7     2
8     3
9     4
10    5
11    6
12    7
13    8
14    9
15    0
16    1
17    2
18    3
19    4
20    5
21    6
22    7
23    8
24    9
```

Can convert back to a pd.DataFrame with [`to_frame`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

```py
print(out.to_frame("test"))
```

```py
    test
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      0
6      1
7      2
8      3
9      4
10     5
11     6
12     7
13     8
14     9
15     0
16     1
17     2
18     3
19     4
20     5
21     6
22     7
23     8
24     9
```